# How do I change the default Screen Options in Wordpress admin area

Tags: wordpress

When editing a page or post in the admin area, you have the ability to enable and disable various screen options.

What I want to accomplish is to make it so that comments are not allowed by default, but can be turned on if the admin wants too. Currently by default it is set to allow comments.

How do I change `allow comments` to false (un-checked) by default ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just paste this in your `functions.php`

```
function comments_off_default( $post_content, $post ) {
    $post->comment_status = 'closed';
    return $post_content;
}
add_filter( 'default_content', 'comments_off_default', 10, 2 );
```

Also you can try [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/page-comments-off-please/).

Comment: Outstanding, thank you. You use a parameter 'closed' but I can not find anything in the Wordpress Function Refrence that shows me what parameters are available. This seems to be different from 'wp set comment status'. Is there any documentation you can point me toward? Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome :) There is nothing on Codex about this, I didn't find but you can `var_dump($post)` in the function to see what it contains.